# Google Fusion Table - Drop-Down example doesn't work

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I've tried to run this code locally, but the map doesn't show up. 
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query

This example uses the same table, except for the drop-down and it works running it locally on my computer. 
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-fusiontables-styling_markers.html

I must be missing something, the table is public so there shouldn't be any access issues.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS issue. In the first sample, the CSS is loaded from a location relative to the sample, here:

```
<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

So if you save that locally, you'll get it looking for a local style. The map won't show up because the map div isn't sized correctly.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help! I found the full url: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css